# How to Do a Proper CONSTRAINT in MariaDB 10.1.37 / Ver 15.1?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB, and I am experiencing trouble with introducing a CONSTRAINT.

My version of MariaDB:

```
Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB
```

My error message:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `schedulingGUI`.`#sql-1043_1a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

My table entry for **city**:

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
  cityId INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  city VARCHAR(50),
  countryId INT unsigned,
  customerName VARCHAR(50),
  address VARCHAR(50),
  postalCode VARCHAR(50),
  phone VARCHAR(50),
  createDate VARCHAR(50),
  createdBy VARCHAR(50),
  lastUpdateBy VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (cityId)
);
```

My table entry for **customer**:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  customerId INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customerName VARCHAR(50),
  addressId INT unsigned,
  active INT unsigned,
  address VARCHAR(50),
  city VARCHAR(50),
  postalCode VARCHAR(50),
  phone VARCHAR(50),
  createDate VARCHAR(50),
  createdBy VARCHAR(50),
  lastUpdateBy VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (customerId)
);
```

My CONSTRAINT entry:

```
ALTER TABLE city
  ADD CONSTRAINT customerNameChange01
  FOREIGN KEY (customerName)
  REFERENCES customer (customerName)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I recently stumbled across SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.  It states the following:

```
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
```

Thank you for your insight.

*EDIT:  Content added.  Corrected the error message.*

Comment: Please add the customer table definition. And why is sql complaining about schedulinggui and you are showing city?

Comment: @P.Salmon  My apology.  I added the error message a bit hastily.  The problem is the same.

Comment: Declare the tables in a particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked:

```
CREATE INDEX CustomerName ON customer (customerName);
```

**SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;** helped a lot.